# Unnesting repeated records to a single row in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset that includes repeated records. When I unnest them I get 2 rows. 1 per nested record.

Before unnest raw data:

[image: ![enter image description here]

After unnest using this query:

```
SELECT
  eventTime
  participant.id
FROM
 `public.table`,
UNNEST(people) AS participant
WHERE
verb = 'event'
```

[image]

These are actually 2 rows that are expanded to 4. I've been trying to unnest into a single row so I have 3 columns,

eventTime, buyer.Id, seller.Id.

I've been trying to use REPLACE to build a struct of the unnested content but I cannot figure out how to do it. Any pointer , documentation or steps that could help me out?

Comment: please correct your "before unnest" data example  - it is definitely missing stuff!! also please check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just did put more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(key) FROM (
  SELECT
    eventTime,
    participant.id,
    personEventRole,
    TO_JSON_STRING(t) key
  FROM `public.table` t,
  UNNEST(people) AS participant
  WHERE verb = 'event'
)
PIVOT (MIN(id) FOR personEventRole IN ('buyer', 'seller'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried? does it work for you?

Comment: yes it works perfectly thx!